# When should I use #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]

Tags: storage

I'm fiddling with substrate's `#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]`
https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/macros/#palletpallet

Documentation says

> Generates the Store trait if the attribute is provided, which contains an associated type for each storage item. It takes the form of a more explicit Rust struct module and can be written as pub struct Pallet(_);, with the appropriate PhantomData replacing _ to make it generic.

Here is my kittens pallet. Even if I remove the macro mentioned above, node works fine as expected.
https://github.com/yourarj/substrate-node-playground/blob/adfafc5e0733ade8fd9b422585716baea11da35a/pallets/kittens/src/lib.rs#L13

I tried applying cargo expand with both cases is that I found out the following differences. A `Store trait` and it's implemented for `Pallet Struct`.
[image]

But in both the cases my functionality is not impacted at all. It mutates chain state and queries the state as expected.

So

> Why should we use this `#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]`? What's the point?

Comment: How do you access the Storage items otherwise?

This link has slightly more info:
https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#macro-expansion-1

Comment: Can you elaborate on this @Georges? I didn't get your point here by `access the Storage item`, do you mean accessing the state of storage?

Comment: Have you built your runtime using `cargo build` and have ran the chain? What check did you do to verify that it "mutates chain state and queries the state as expected" ?

Comment: Ran the chain after building with `cargo build`. And checked with polkadot.js chainstate and extrinsics. Worked perfectly identcal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is an artifact from the the old design for how we collected all the different storage items in the `decl_storage!` macro in FRAME v1.

Here is an example definition:

```rust
crate::decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Config> as Runtime {
        Value get(fn value) config(): (u64, u64);
        NumberMap: map hasher(identity) u32 => u64;
        DoubleMap: double_map hasher(identity) u32, hasher(identity) u32 => u64;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the old macro simply wrapped an entire `trait Store`, and generated all the storage items using this.

When redesigning FRAME storage for FRAME v2, an individual `type` pattern was used:

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
pub type Value<T> = StorageValue<_, u32>;

#[pallet::storage]
pub type Map<T> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, u8, u16>;

#[pallet::storage]
pub type DoubleMap<T> =
    StorageDoubleMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, u8, Twox64Concat, u16, u32>;
```

To maintain backwards compatibility, this extra `generate_store` attribute was created. It should not affect you as a pallet developer if you use it or not.

Answer (score 4):

The `Store` trait, as you see, just creates some aliases, and is completely optional.

For example, with this trait, you can access all of the storage items regardless of being `pub` or not as associated type `Pallet`. Although, in FRAME v2 all storage items have to be `pub(crate)` at the minimum, and I think the `Store` trait only exists in FRAME v2 for backwards compatibility and will likely be removed in further versions.

Comment: Can I say `Store` trait is deprecated after FRAME V2? By the way just out of curiosity, can you tell what was it's usecase under what circumstances a developer need those aliases?

Comment: I am using FRAME v2 and in v2 there is no error when declaring the Storage with private visibility.
But also Id didn't found any difference b/w pub(super) and private for the storage because in both case I am able to access it from PolkadotJs Explorer

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried to declare storage as private as below

#[pallet::pallet]
#[pallet::generate_store(trait Store)]
pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter( fn running_status)]
type SystemRunnig<T> = StorageValue<_, bool, ValueQuery>;
```

It compiles fine and even I am able to access and see the status of the SystemRunnig from polkadotJs explorer.

So here what is meant via declaring it private.
can you explain